# Dynamically Widen Tooltip

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I want a tooltip to widen instead of extending off the bottom of the page. I've got a tooltip that can be quite long and as the max-width is 200px it is extending off the bottom of the page.

I am able to hardcode the max-width of the tooltip with

```
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 350px;
}
```

which helps but when the tooltip is shorter I don't want the width to increase, only when the tooltip will disappear off the page.

This fiddle has a basic example of what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/76xz3jog/1/

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn");

const buttonText = "A button"
const tooltipText = "A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. A long tooltip. "

button.innerHTML = buttonText;
button.setAttribute("title", tooltipText);

$('#btn').tooltip();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-cp9JSDyi0CDCvBfFKYLWXevb3r8hRv5JxcxLkUq/LEtAmOg7X0yzR3p0x/g+S3aWcZw18mhxsCXyelKWmXgzzg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-PxtG6eoPtr5QdgWieDr0Bsa0+IXe2qRAG/8gSw/pBWZWcXQRAhWU4lEumKTjmOMjgmen3q/robV+RD3sqwR36g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"></button>
```

[Instead of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLAVd.png)

[It will hopefully look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSLQK.png)

Answer (score 0):

"only when the tooltip will disappear off the page." can you please put some light on this, it's a bit unclear from the description what you want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding! The last two links in my question show what I've got and what I'm hoping for. Is that clear enough?